# is it possible to create dojo chart without axis?

Tags: charts, dojo, dojox.charting

I'm using a dojo chart to display data in a bubble chart.  However, I don't need the axis but if I remove the axis, it screws up the display of the data.  I can fudge axis not being there by hiding labels and coloring the lines white but then there's still this large margin on the left and bottom of the chart.  How do you make a dojo chart without the axis while still having the min/max set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chart1.addAxis("x",{ type : 'Invisible' /*, .... */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Matthew, if you are still looking to tweak the margins, the solution here:
[dojox charting: remove the padding around the chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719495/dojox-charting-remove-the-padding-around-the-chart)
worked for me.